# Applying default page styles to html returned from an ajax call

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, datatables

How can I apply the default css and jquery files I have referenced in my view to the HTML that is generated in my jquery datatables fnRender property?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#users-search-results').dataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "UsersAjaxHandler",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "aoColumns": [
                        { "sName": "NAME" },
                        { "sName": "REQUESTS_REMAINING" },
                        { "sName": "LAST_REQUEST" },
                        { "sName": "EMAIL" },
                        {
                            "sName": "UserId",
                            "bSearchable": false,
                            "bSortable": false,
                            "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                                @*//<script src="~/js/theme.js"></script>*@
                                // oObj.aData[0] returns the userId
                                return "<button class='btn glow'>Drop down</button>"
                        + "<button class='btn glow dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>"
                            + "<span class='caret'></span>"
                        + "</button>"
                        + "<ul class='dropdown-menu'>"
                            + "<li><a href='#'>Option one</a></li>"
                            + "<li><a href='#'>Option two</a></li>"
                            + "<li><a href='#'>Option three</a></li>"
                            + "<li><a href='#'>Option four</a></li>"
                        + "</ul>"
                    + "</div>";

                            }

                        }
        ]
    });
});
```

When the html loads it has no styling or functionality. I've tried including the script and css declarations in the actual HTML code for property fnRender but that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Style the content in-line for dynamically generated content. To have functionality, you need to attach event handlers after the content has been generated. Try using jQuery on().

http://api.jquery.com/on/